# How to pass value from a function to a promise?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a function that I would like to pass a value from on to a promise.

I've written a stripped down version for the sake of this example.
In the real version, the promise is necessary and contains many other functions. I've just included the alert as a simple way of determining whether the value has been passed.
The code all works apart from getting the right value in the alert.

In the example, I would like "value" to be passed on as an alert in the promise. How do I achieve this? Where should I write 'value' - to the right of 'reject' in the first promise line, as I have done here, or elsewhere?

Thanks in advance!

```
$(".button").on('click', () => {

  var value = 12345;

  mypromise("+ value +").then(() => {
    Anotherfunction();
  });

});

const mypromise =() => new Promise(function(resolve, reject, value) {

  alert( value );
  resolve();
})
```

Comment: `const mypromise = value => ...`

Comment: Declare the parameter to the mypromise function? The callback to the promise constructor will close over it. Also, async? Huh? It's a *Promise*.

Comment: @JaredSmith Sorry just removed that for the sake of simplicity. It's part of a large portion of code, in which the async is necessary!

Comment: @JosefHolmes I don't see where the async could be necessary in a promise... the concept of a promise is to be async.

Comment: @JosefHolmes it isn't necessary. The return value of the function passed to the Promise constructor is completely ignored, and there's no reason to `await` inside a function passed to the Promise constructor when you can just add another `.then` on to the chain.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes you can, but not written like this...

```
$(".button").on('click', () => {
  var value = 12345;
  mypromise(`+ ${value} +`).then((result) => {
    Anotherfunction(result);
  });
});

const mypromise = (value) => {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      alert( value );
      resolve();
  })
}
```

Comment: Note the alert will be a literal string `"+ value +"` and not `12345` that gets alerted.

Comment: That's great, thank you! I'll accept this when I'm allowed to in a few mins. I just realised that I don't need the 'plusses' to pass the value on, simply (value) on it's own

Comment: you're welcome. If you want to read more about promises use the official doc : https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise :)